# "Cannot assign to the result of this expression" error arising from a variable (var)

Tags: swift, subclass, enumeration, scenekit

I have defined the following subclass whose main property is linked to an enumeration:

```
let NumberOfColors: UInt32 = 6

enum SphereColor: Int, Printable {
case Red = 0, Yellow, Blue, Green, Purple, White

var sphereName: String {
    switch self {
    case .Red:
        return "red"
    case .Yellow:
        return "yellow"
    case .Blue:
        return "blue"
    case .Green:
        return "green"
    case .Purple:
        return "purple"
    case .White:
        return "white"
    }
}

var description: String {
    return self.sphereName
}

static func random() -> SphereColor {
    return SphereColor(rawValue: Int(arc4random_uniform(NumberOfColors - 1)))!
    }
}


class Sphere: SCNSphere {
var color : SphereColor

init(radius: CGFloat, color: SphereColor) {
    self.color = color
    super.init()
    switch color.rawValue as Int {
    case 0:
        self.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.redColor()
    case 1:
        self.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.yellowColor()
    case 2:
        self.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.blueColor()
    case 3:
        self.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.greenColor()
    case 4:
        self.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.purpleColor()
    case 5:
        self.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.whiteColor()
    default:
        break
    }
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Instantiating it using

```
let sphere = Sphere(radius: radius, color: SphereColor.random()) 

let sphereNode = SCNNode(geometry: sphere)
```

works fine, but when I select one of the nodes and try to change its color property with

```
// node selection...
var geom = node.geometry! as! Sphere
geom.color.rawValue = 5
```

I get the "Cannot assign to the result of this expression" error, but I haven't declared the color property as a constant and don't understand why this is happening. I assume I have made some fundamental mistake in the code relative to the Sphere class, any ideas on what this could be?

EDIT: using

```
geom.color = SphereColor(rawValue: 5)!
```

as Martin R said, allows me to build and run my code but the color of the sphere doesn't change, which makes me think there's still something wrong with my subclass declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Props to @MartinR for fixing the first problem, but my response for the rest of it is too big for a comment.

As noted, `rawValue` is a read-only property of an enum. Enums are [value types](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH13-ID88), so you don't change the value of an "instance" of the enum, you create a new value. (Think of enums as fancy numbers. You don't change 7 *itself* into another number, you change a variable holding the value 7 to hold another value.) To create an enum value from the corresponding raw type, use the `init(rawValue:)` initializer.

Your second problem is that you're updating the model (the part that tells you what color you think your ball is, in a conceptual / semantic way) but you're setting the visual representation of that model (the SceneKit stuff you can see) only when you create a `Sphere`, not when you set its `color` property. If you want to keep model and view in sync, you need to make that happen.

You already have code for translating a `Color` into a SceneKit material color, in your initializer. Factor that out so you can also call it from someplace else, and then you can use it to update your view when the model changes — say, with a [property observer](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID262).

Here's that, plus some other improvements:

```
class Sphere: SCNSphere {

    func setMaterialColor(sphereColor: SphereColor) {
        let color: UIColor
        // Switch on the enum, not the int.
        // That way the compiler can check exhaustiveness,
        // and you don't need a dead default case.
        switch sphereColor {
            case .Red:
                // Use a temporary for the color choice so 
                // you're only setting the material property once.
                color = UIColor.redColor()
            case .Yellow:
                color = UIColor.yellowColor()
            case .Blue:
                color = UIColor.blueColor()
            case .Green:
                color = UIColor.greenColor()
            case .Purple:
                color = UIColor.purpleColor()
            case .White:
                color = UIColor.whiteColor()
        }
        // Force-unwrap firstMaterial -- we "know" it should be non-nil,
        // so it's better to find out the hard way if something weird has happened.
        // (Either that or test the optional so you can manage failure specifically.)
        self.firstMaterial!.diffuse.contents = color
    }

    var color : SphereColor {
        didSet {
            self.setMaterialColor(color)
        }
    }

    init(radius: CGFloat, color: SphereColor) {
        self.color = color
        super.init()
        self.setMaterialColor(color)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) { /* ... */ }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`rawValue` is a read-only property and you cannot assign a new value
to it. You have to create a `SphereColor` from
the raw value and assign it to the `color` property:

```
geom.color = SphereColor(rawValue: 5)!
```

or if there is *any* chance that the raw value might be out-of-range
and no matching color exists:

```
if let color = SphereColor(rawValue: 5) {
    geom.color = color
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. That change allows me to build and run my program but the color of the sphere is not modified in any way, which makes me think there's still some issue in the subclass declaration.